# How to use regular expression as keys in a dictionary, and how do you access using it?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with a tuple as keys. Inside the tuple is a number and regular expression. The tuple as key correspond to a any value. I wanted to access the value using the tuple (i.e. regular expression) as keys. For example,

```
import re

t_dict = dict()
t[(1, r"[0-9]+")] = "Hello world!"
t[(2, r"[a-z]+")] = "Hi!"
```

Am I doing the right thing in putting a regular expression on it? If not, how do you put a regular expression on it?

Next is I want to get the values in the dictionary using the keys. For example, I want to do it this way.

```
print t[(1, '99')] # this should print "Hello world!"
print t[(2, 'hey')] # this should print "Hi!"
```

Comment: There is no built in support for your use case. As dictionary is simply a key value pair, there doesn't exist such pattern based support. And, this is not looking a decent data structure as well. May be you could tell us your use cases from more higher level, so we might suggest you a different approach.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; the point of a dictionary is that it's a hash table, so you can look up value by key in `O(1)`. You could write a data structure that does what you want, but it would have to do a `O(n)` scan over the regex "keys" to find the matching values.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean, sirs. I found a code that works like this t[(1, 'a')] = "Hello World!", t[(2, 'b')] = "Hi!". So, retrieving the value, "Hello World" is just t[(1, 'a')].

I am trying to simulate a DFA using dictionaries as a list of transitions of my DFA. So, the regular expressions I wrote in there means "any number from 0-infinite" and all strings only with letters from a-z.

Comment: In DFA, it is possible to have different regular expression but have the same starting state. For example, t[(1, r"[0-9]+")] and t[(1, r"[^0-9]+")]

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you can subclass the builtin dictionary, then overwrite it's `__getitem__` method to have the kind of lookup you want.

The problem with this approach is that you will not be able to reproduce the `O(1)` lookup of an actual dictionary, since Python's inbuilt hash function doesn't understand regexes (and I don't know of any hash that does).

There is no easy way to have an `O(1)` (constant time) reverse lookup to find which regular expression matches a string. You cannot know which whether a regular expression matches a string unless you've actually tried it.

Comment: The lookup time would be very close to O(1) since the only additional overhead is applying the regex to the supplied key. Regardless, I would upvote your answer if it included code showing how to to **override** the `__setitem__()` method inherited from its `dict` baseclass.

Comment: @martineau, `"The lookup time would be very close to O(1) since the only additional overhead is applying the regex to the supplied key."`. Not quite. You'd have to test the input string for the lookup against *every* regular expression, since any of them _could_ match. There's no guarantee that an input lookup string matches only one of the regular expressions, and even if there were, you have no way of telling without actually checking against each of them.

Comment: @martineau, `"The lookup time would be very close to O(1) since the only additional overhead is applying the regex to the supplied key."`. Not quite. You'd have to test the input string for the lookup against *every* regular expression, since any of them _could_ match. There's no guarantee that an input lookup string matches only one of the regular expressions, and even if there were, you have no way of telling without actually checking against each of them.

Comment: Seems to me from the examples in the OP's question that which _single_ regex to use is being indicated because each key is a tuple whose first value looks like it's which regex to use when checking for a match.